# Shall I add question+answer pair for already found program? For my own program?

Tags: discussion, policy, self-answer, advertising

Imagine following scenarios:

1. I looked for a program, failed to find it. Though about asking on softrecs, but tried more search and actually found it;
2. I looked for a program, failed to find it. Though about asking on softrecs. Then implemented myself;
3. I remembered that I looked for a program and, failing to find, implemented it and want the program to be more visible to other users, so thinking about adding it to softwarerecs;
4. I just know about some awesome program, but there are not mentions about it on softwarerecs or SE in general, so thinking about bumping it up using softwarerecs.

In which scenarios it is appropriate to add the question + answer pair for a pre-known program?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the rules for self-answering your question?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/131/what-are-the-rules-for-self-answering-your-question)

Comment: @Braiam, Tha main point of the question is that it is going from answer to question. Advices in "What are the rules for self-answering your question?" mostly hold for other StackExchange sites while "I found a cool program, let's think up a usage scenario and add it to SoftRecs" seems SoftRecs-specific.

Comment: If it is your own program, you would need to disclose it - Assuming that the question was aimed at a useful purpose and there was time to propose alternate software if it exists, I think it would be OK, but I am tempted to say it might be better only if it was FLOSS to prevent advertisement.

Comment: IMHO Q&A is good whenever you feel that it can save other people's time (i.e. it wasn't straightforward for you to find the right solution) or make them discover something that wouldn't have thought about.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. No problem go ahead if you want to
2. possibly conflicty: Are you only using SoftwareRecs to advertise? If yes that is questionable. Is it Open-Source? If yes that decreases questionability. If paid software it gets really sounding like advertising. Basically if you use SR for other purposes and you won't be getting monetary benefits it is probably okay, otherwise probably not.
3. basically same as #2;
4. No problem, go ahead if you want.

That is a **general** guidelines only of course.

Answer (score 4):

[It has the official seal of approval](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)

1 and 4 are *definitely absolutely ok* - Ask a question as a question, self answer as an answer, and self select as an answer once you can.

2 and 3 you need to be careful about - remember to disclose appropriately, and to ensure your sole purpose here is *not just to promote your software*. Don't make your answer look like ad copy - as a developer, you're in the *unique* position of knowing your software inside and out, and as such, you're expected to (as much as anyone else) tailor your answer to the *actual problem*